# About keeping observation with specified criteria in SAS

Tags: sas

Hello and many thanks in advance for your answers and efforts to help newby users in this forum.

i have a sas table with the variables : ID, Year, Month, and Creation date.
What i desire is, per month and year and Creation date to keep only one ID.
My HAVE data is :

```
ID  Year    Month   Date of creation
1   2019    1       a
1   2019    1       a
1   2019    1       b
1   2019    2       c
1   2019    3       d
1   2020    5       e
2   2019    1       a
2   2019    1       b
2   2019    3       c
3   2021    8       m
3   2021    9       k
```

My WANT data is

```
ID  Year    Month   Date of creation
1   2019    1       a
1   2019    1       b
1   2019    2       c
1   2019    3       d
1   2020    5       e
2   2019    1       a
2   2019    1       b
2   2019    3       c
3   2021    8       m
3   2021    9       k
```

I tried nodup key but it removes ID's.

Answer (score 1):

Your example seems to work fine with NODUPKEY option of PROC SORT.  Perhaps you used the wrong BY variables?

```
data have;
  input ID  Year    Month  Creation $ ;
cards;
1   2019    1       a
1   2019    1       a
1   2019    1       b
1   2019    2       c
1   2019    3       d
1   2020    5       e
2   2019    1       a
2   2019    1       b
2   2019    3       c
3   2021    8       m
3   2021    9       k
;
proc sort data=have out=want nodupkey;
  by id year month creation ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use distinct clause from proc sql, it will remove duplicates based on all columns

```
proc sql;
create table want 
as
select distinct * from have;
quit;
```